# Use scrollview and adjustPan together android

Tags: android

My code is

in my manifest I have written

```
 <activity android:name=".email" android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">        </activity>
```

And in my layout I have written

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@color/white">

        <ImageView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="@drawable/ic_backdrop_wave"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:id="@+id/bottomImage" />
          <ScrollView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"       
                android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
                            android:isScrollContainer="false">
                <LinearLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                                    android:orientation="vertical">
                               <EditText></EditText>
                               <EditText></EditText>
                               <EditText></EditText>
                       </LinearLayout>
            </ScrollView>
        </RelativeLayout>
```

So, When I clicked on any edit text it will not re sizes the imageview but It will also disable scroll view.

Now what I have to do to come out.

Answer (score 0):

Please try This..

```
<activity android:name=".email" android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">        </activity>
```

Comment: if u not got ur answer plz read this http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html